# Go Anonymous Method For A Structure

Tags: go

Does Go support anonymous methods for structures and if they do how do you create and call them?

This is the code I've been trying to get work but I'm unsure if Go(go version go1.1.2 linux/amd64) supports anonymous methods to structures.

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
)

type Person struct{
  name string
  age int
}

func (p Person) get_details() string {
  return fmt.Sprintf("Name->%s, Age->%d", p.name, p.age)
}

func main() {
  p := Person{name:"G4143", age:5}

  //simple anonymous function which works
  fmt.Println(func(i int)int{return i * i}(34))

  str := p.get_details()

  fmt.Println(str)

  //anonymous method which won't compile
  str = p.func(p Person)()string{return fmt.Sprintf("Name->%s, Age->%d", p.name, p.age) }()

  fmt.Println(str)
}
```

I thank-you for any guidance..

Comment: Can you please explain what was the real goal ? Why would you want an anonymous function to have the form of a method ? Some kind of sugar ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that, however you have 3 options :

Private method :

```
type Person struct{
    name string
    age int
}

func (p Person) Details() string { // public
    return fmt.Sprintf("Name->%s, Age->%d", p.name, p.age)
}

func (p Person) details() string { // private, notice the lowercase D
    return fmt.Sprintf("Name->%s, Age->%d", p.name, p.age)
}
```

Use the inline function just like this :

```
str = func()string{return fmt.Sprintf("Name->%s, Age->%d", p.name, p.age) }()
```

Pass the variable to the inline function :

```
str = func(p Person) string { return fmt.Sprintf("Name->%s, Age->%d", p.name, p.age) }(p)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I wasn't sure if it was possible and its nice to know that's its not. I'll guess I'll get that notion out of my head and go with a conventional solution like you posted.

Answer (score 3):

No, that's not possible, but more importantly you don't need that because of the closure system : `p` is already available in your function, like the other variables of the external scope.

```
str = func()string{return fmt.Sprintf("Name->%s, Age->%d", p.name, p.age) }()
```

Answer (score -2):

No. As this answer is to short: There is really no way to do this. BTW I cannot see any reason to do this.